# I accidentally denied xcode permission to something

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am a noob developer, who just got into developing for macOS. I've just done the most simple web browser in history, (with two buttons) and I ran the build. For the first time it asked me about 5 times for my login item, I entered them all, but accidentally clicked "deny" on one of them. Now my build keeps telling me an error that says, "Swift stdlib tool Error, Task failed with exit 1 signal 0"

Is there ANY way to make Xcode make me enter those passwords again?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to delete the DerviedData by using rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData? It's not a problem if you delete it because XCode will recreate it after you build something.